# get fb pixel id using api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-pixel

I was looking for any way of getting the fb pixel id using the graph api or the list of fb pixel id for an fb account using the fb login oauth flow. But after looking at various docs , I couldn't find any api call that would return such data.
From Graph Api explorer:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

I tried using the adaccounts to get the id and then the pixel id but this did not work:
 /v2.11/me/adaccounts

To get adaccount id

then

/v2.11/act_729987647077200/adspixels

This returned

{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#274) The ad account is not enabled for usage in Ads API. Please add it in developers.facebook.com/apps -> select your app -> settings -> advanced -> advertising accounts -> Ads API. Account 729987647077200 not enabled for this application.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 274,
    "fbtrace_id": "GYRwLPodWzg"
  }
}

This required me setup the ad account in my app.

But for my use case I just want the users pixel id of the fb pixel to start tracking the users website that I have with me hosted. So that the user can see the tracking in his account of his website.

I wanted to automate the process of pixel id by fb oauth login and permissions flow instead of asking user to manually provide the pixel id by copy paste.

Answer (score 1):

What you write is correct and should work
`/act_<ACCOUNT_ID>/adspixels`
will return you the pixel ids.

You can then get information about the pixel with

`/<PIXEL_ID>?fields=name,owner_ad_account,is_unavailable,last_fired_time,owner_business`

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/adspixels/